# Create Custom Python Model in Azure ML Studio?

Tags: python, machine-learning-model, azure-ml

I came across this article on how to create a Custom R Model and use it in Azure ML studio

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/create-r-model

Can we create a Python model instead ? While I have seen articles of python scripts for evaluation or data processing , I haven't not found enough documents on creating / using custom model built using Python ?

All I have to do is , expose my custom model as web / rest service

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/python-language-modules This article describes the modules provided in Azure Machine Learning Studio that support running custom Python code in a machine learning experiment.

Comment: Links only answers may go redundant in future. Please provide more content to improve the answer and make it more useful.